# Access violation writing location 0x00000000. When increase size of array to calloc

Tags: c, access-violation, calloc

I try to calloc 2d array and initial value of edge cell with 255, it work correctly but when I try to set dimension of array over than 12000*12000, VS2010 show  Access violation writing location 0x00000000

my function of calloc 2d array

```
int **calloc_2d_int(int Rows, int Cols) {
      int *data = (int *)calloc(Rows*Cols,sizeof(int));
      int **array= (int **)calloc(Rows,sizeof(int*));
      for (int i=0; i<Rows; i++)
           array[i] = &(data[Cols*i]);
      return array;
}
```

main function

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   

int i,j;

/*convert string to int*/
int row    = atoi(argv[1]);
int column      = atoi(argv[2]); 
int T           = atoi(argv[3]); 

int** s[2];

s[0] = calloc_2d_int(row,column);
s[1] = calloc_2d_int(row,column); 
for(i=0 ; i<row ; i++){
    s[0][i][0]        = 255;   //error at this line 
    s[1][i][0]        = 255;
    s[0][i][column-1] = 255;
    s[1][i][column-1] = 255;
}

for(i=0 ; i<column ; i++){
    s[0][0][i] = 255;
    s[1][0][i] = 255;
    s[0][row-1][i] = 255;
    s[1][row-1][i] = 255;

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Out of interest, why are you even using C-style memory allocation with `calloc` in a C++ program ?

Comment: Also I suggest you check the values of `row`, and particularly `column`, after the calls to `atoi()`, to make sure they are both > 0.

Comment: I have checked it and it correctly.

Comment: Maybe `calloc()` returns NULL? It is 32 bit?

Comment: What values are you using for `row` and `column` ? Are they large ? Is it possible that `calloc` fails (NB: you have no error checking for this) ?

Comment: When dialog alert ,i just 0 ,it mean that it have error since start for.

Comment: I use row = 13000 and column = 13000

Comment: Another nice example showing why one shall always test the out come of calls to relevant library functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Access violation writing location 0x00000000

This means you are trying to write on a `NULL` pointer. So `calloc` returned `NULL`.

As you can read on the [calloc manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc), it returns `NULL` on error, which can be a too big memory request.
Depending of your system, 13000 * 13000 (169 000 000) might be too big.

Always check `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` returns for an error.